# What is the format for standard ARINC 429 labels with 20 sig bits?

Tags: arinc-429

Certain standard labels in the ARINC 429 specification have 20 significant bits. For example, Label 110 (GNSS Latitude) has a range of +/- 180 degrees, with a resolution of .000172 degrees. In order to accomplish this, how is the word formatted? Does the data run into the SDI field like so?

| Bit # | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 1-8 | Label (110) |
| 9 | 0.000171661377 |
| 10 | 0.0003433227539 |
| 11 | 0.0006866455078 |
| 12 | 0.001373291016 |
| 13 | 0.002746582031 |
| 14 | 0.005493164063 |
| 15 | 0.01098632813 |
| 16 | 0.02197265625 |
| 17 | 0.0439453125 |
| 18 | 0.087890625 |
| 19 | 0.17578125 |
| 20 | 0.3515625 |
| 21 | 0.703125 |
| 22 | 1.40625 |
| 23 | 2.8125 |
| 24 | 5.625 |
| 25 | 11.25 |
| 26 | 22.5 |
| 27 | 45 |
| 28 | 90 |
| 29 | Sign (0/1) |
| 30 | SSM |
| 31 | SSM |
| 32 | Parity |

Or does the sign bit move to bit 31, replacing the SSM instead?

Answer (score 2):

The extra bits of precision would use the SDI bits as you've suggested.

From ARINC 429 Part 1 dated May 17th 2004

> 2.1.4 Source/Destination Identifier

> Bit Numbers 9 and 10 of numeric data words should be
> reserved for a data source/destination identification
> function. They are not available for this function in
> alpha/numeric (ISO Alphabet Number 5) data words (see
> Section 2.3.1.3 of this document) or when the resolution
> needed for numeric (BNR/BCD) data necessitates their use
> of valid data.